# Can i create different SAS tokens with different permissions on the same blob container for two separate people

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Can I create two different SAS tokens

- with different permissions,
- expiry time
- and source IP
- on the same blob container

But **for two** separate people?

Answer (score 0):

> Can i create two different SAS tokens with different permissions,
>   expiry time and source ip on the same blob container for two separate
>   people

Yes, it is certainly possible to do so. You can create as many SAS tokens as you would like by using different combinations of permissions, expiry time and source IP address.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav     So, does it mean if i've already generated a SAS token few days back. I can still generate another on same blob and send to different vendor to consume. Hoping the file drop for earlier vendor will not stop and both will have different SAS tokens based on requirements. One need to drop files, another need to consume.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, let me test that out.        Also, i believe i cant put multiple IP addresses at the time of SAS token generation for IP restriction, i can only put one IP or a range .

Comment: Correct again regarding IP address.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to do this in data lake!?